# The subselect is fast with few rows, but the outer select is slow

Tags: sql-server

I have the following and it returns 5 rows instantaneously:

```
SELECT CollID
FROM FabricView
WHERE MfgID = 30023
GROUP BY CollID
```

But, then when I do the following, it takes 9 seconds:

```
SELECT CollID,CollName
FROM Coll
WHERE CollID IN(
    SELECT CollID
    FROM FabricView
    WHERE MfgID = 30023
    GROUP BY CollID
)
```

I would think that because the inner select goes so quickly, and only returns 5 rows, then the outer select would also be instantaneous, but it's not.

Edit: Rewriting it this way produces a fast result:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT CollID
    FROM FabricView
    WHERE MfgID = 30023
    GROUP BY CollID
)
SELECT Coll.CollID,CollName
FROM Coll
JOIN CTE 
ON Coll.CollID = CTE.CollID
```

Comment: Do you have indexes on the second table (`Col1`)?

Comment: @MartinSmith using hard coded values runs fast. Coll is a lookup table with 37 rows.

Comment: How do I get the execution plan in text so that I can copy/paste it? (Dumb question I'm sure)

Comment: In managenment studio select "Include Actual Execution Plan" on the query menu. Run both slow and fast together. Right click the plan image and view XML then upload that to pastebin or somewhere as it will likely be too long to add to the question.

Comment: In your last query with the CTE you're using CollView instead of the table Coll.

Comment: OK, it's 400 lines long, but here it is!  http://pastebin.com/mS1WMNqz

Comment: Oh wait, the 2nd execution plan is here: http://pastebin.com/NfWWuu6N

Comment: Big discrepancy in actual vs estimated number of executions in the bottom right of the slow plan.

Comment: @Phillip You still haven't commented on that your second query is using `CollView` instead of `Coll`

Comment: @Lamak, thanks for seeing that.  The CTE runs fast, and actually would run a teensy-tiny bit faster if I used the table instead of the view. I'll go ahead and change the view to the table in my edit though.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't see the execution plan for the CTE version?

Answer (score 1):

If you have resolved (I think yes) with your last query ignore this answer:

Instead you can use EXISTS statement instead od IN clause, in this way:

```
SELECT CollID,CollName
FROM Coll
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 'FABRIC'
    FROM FabricView F
    WHERE F.MfgID = 30023
    AND F.CollID = Coll.CollID
)
```

In this way you don't use GROUP BY, EXISTS is more efficient than IN, in the last version of Sql Server (since 2008).

Comment: `EXISTS` and `IN` pretty much always give the same plan since 2005 AFAIK. Also the conclusion of [this article](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/) Can you provide a repro where they don't? (`NOT EXISTS` is preferable to `NOT IN` though)

Comment: Thanks Joe!  That works too. I even replaced 'FABRIC' with * and it works just as fast.  Interesting...

Comment: @Phillip - And if you try `SELECT CollID,CollName FROM Coll WHERE CollID IN(SELECT CollID FROM FabricView WHERE MfgID = 30023)`? Which keeps the `IN` and removes the redundant `GROUP BY`?

Comment: @MartinSmith, still runs slow.  So that tells me that SQL Server must be ignoring the group by.

Comment: @Phillip - Yes. The plan you put up for `IN` doesn't have any aggregation so it looked as though that was getting optimised out. Would you mind uploading the actual execution plans for  `EXISTS` (this answer) and the CTE version? I'd like to try and figure out why the `EXISTS` gives a different plan in this case.